# Colocar Funções Objetivas na mesma escala(0,1)?

Tags: python

tenho esse código para a geração da função fitness, mas preciso que os valores resultantes das funções F1, F2 E F3, sejam calculados de tal forma que seus valores estejam sempre na mesma escala de (0,1).

```
    # objetivo 1 - minimize - f1
  def f1(self):
      return self.M/K   

  # objetivo 2 - maximize - f2
  def f2(self):
      try:
        return 1/(N*k)*self.somatorio_covCost_s[0]
      except ValueError as e:
        print(e)   

  # objetivo 3 - maximize - f3 
  def f3(self): 
      v_f3=0
      try:
        v_f3=1/(self.M*m)*self.somatorio_connCost_s[0]         
      except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
      return v_f3


  def ffitness(self):
    peso = pesos()
    w1 = peso[0]
    w2 = peso[1]
    w3 = peso[2]

    f=w1*(1.0 - self.f1())+w2*(self.f2())+w3*(self.f3())
    print("F1(Minimize):",self.f1())
    print("F2(Maximize):",self.f2())
    print("F3(Maximize):",self.f3())
    print("Pesos: w1:"+str(w1)+" "+"w2:"+str(w2)+" "+"w3:"+str(w3))
    print("Resultado da Função Fitness:",f)

    self.fitness=f
    #return f
```

Comment: Consegue fazer um [mcve] demonstrando o código funcionando?

Comment: mto extenso pra colocar aki.Tenho como resultado isso): F1(Minimize): 0.6  F2(Maximize): 2.7, F3(Maximize): 2.0 ,Pesos: w1:0.3447301953796229 w2:0.2582778887500879 w3:0.39699191587028, Resultado da Função Fitness: 1.6292262095176                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  O resultado da função fitness ñ poderia dá >1, e para isso precisava q o valores das funções f1,f2,f3 estivessem na escala(0,1).

Comment: Mas o cálculo está correto? Não vejo muito sentido em forçar a alteração na escala apenas porque o resultado deveria ser menor que 1.

Comment: sim, o calculo está correto.  quero fazer isso pq geralmente, esses três valores têm diferentes escalas de escala e o maior valor do intervalo sempre domina o valor geral de adequação. Dessa forma, para dar igual importância aos três objetivos individuais, seus valores devem ser ajustados dentro da mesma escala. A parte do ser menor que realmente não entendi mto pq, vou estudar e voltar em quem me orientou para entender, mas todo jeito preciso q os valores estejam na escala.